# Julia LightGraphs weakly_connected_components

Tags: julia, directed-graph, lightgraphs

Isn't it true that the weakly_connected_components in julia LightGraphs should provide connected components where if The DiGraph is turned into an undirected graph, then each component should be connected?
I have tried this and I do not receive such components? As an example I have tried this on the political blogs data as an undirected network

```
data=readdlm(path,',',Int64) #contains edges in each row
N_ = length(unique(vcat(data[:,1],data[:,2]))) ##to get number of vertices
network  = LightGraphs.DiGraph(N_)
#construct the network
for i in 1:size(data,1)
    add_edge!(network, Edge(data[i,1], data[i,2]))
end
#largest weakly connected component
net = weakly_connected_components(network)[1]
temp_net,vmap = induced_subgraph(network, net)
```

and after getting the largest weakly connected component, I see the following:

```
isempty([i for i in vertices(temp_net) if isempty(edges(temp_net).adj[i])])

julia>false
```

which signigies some nodes have no incoming or outgoing edges.
What can be the problem? I am using the latest release 6, but the LightGraphs package tests seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TL;DR answer is that `edges(temp_net).adj[i]` contains only the vertices `i` connects to, and not those connecting to `i`. And some vertices have no incoming edges.

The longer version, is the following which shows `temp_net` in a randomly generated network and assigned as in the question is indeed weakly-connected. First building a random network with:

```
julia> using LightGraphs

julia> N_ = 1000 ;

julia> network  = LightGraphs.DiGraph(N_)
{1000, 0} directed simple Int64 graph

julia> using Distributions

julia> for i in 1:N_
           add_edge!(network, sample(1:N_,2)...)
       end

julia> net = weakly_connected_components(network)[1]

julia> temp_net,vmap = induced_subgraph(network, net)
({814, 978} directed simple Int64 graph, [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13  …  989, 990, 991, 993, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999, 1000])
```

And, now, we have:

```
julia> length(vertices(temp_net))
814

julia> invertices = union((edges(temp_net).adj[i] for i in vertices(temp_net))...);

julia> outvertices = [i for i in vertices(temp_net) if !isempty(edges(temp_net).adj[i])] ;

julia> length(union(invertices,outvertices))
814
```

Thus all 814 vertices either have edges from, or to them (or both) and are part of the weakly connected component.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @dan-getz said, I must implore you not to access any internal data fields of structures - we have accessors for everything that's "public". Specifically, `edges(temp_net).adj` is not guaranteed to be available. It's currently the same as `fadj(g)`, the forward adjacency list of `g`, for both directed and undirected graphs, but it's not intended to be used except to help keep edge iteration state.

If you use `.adj`, your code will break on you without warning at some point.